# Russian script doesn't work in Beamer

Tags: beamer, xetex, babel, cyrillic

I am having an issue with using Babel in Beamer. I am running the presentation in XeLaTeX, and whenever I try to use Cyrillic via Babel it gives me a regular B rather than Б. I've got it to work in a regular LaTeX document find, but for some reason it won't work in Beamer. Below is my preamble and slide:

```
\documentclass{beamer}



 \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[american,russian]{babel}



 \usepackage{lmodern}



\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[fragile]{\hspace{0pt plus 1 filll}\LARGE }

\begin{enumerate}[]
\item<2->{\color{black}\small \foreignlanguage{russian}{B}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't post fragments, but instead one single MWE. PLus if this is just about russian text then this MWE can be reduced quite a lot. Plus the MWE is using resources we do not have access to (the image)

Comment: @daleif Sorry; I trimmed it down to just the portion I'm having issues with.

Comment: In your example, the default lang is Russian, so `\foreignlanguage` is probably irrelevant. As far as I can tell the issue is missing support for Russian in the font being used.

Comment: never use inputenc with xetex, and `\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}` will usually lead to poor results as well.  xetex is designed to use opentype (Unicode) fonts and most will include cyrillic

Comment: don't use T2A together with xelatex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle even the most stripped down beamer example + xelatex gives me `Missing character` in the log using TL19 frozen

Comment: @daleif latin modern doesn't have cyrillic but most "normal" opentype fonts as come with the operating system do.

Comment: See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization#Cyrillic_script .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is best to avoid legacy 8bit TeX encodings with xetex.

You can use any OpenType font that has Cyrillic, I use Arial here:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}


 \usepackage[american,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}



\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Здравствуйте}

\begin{enumerate}[]
\item<2->{\color{black}\small Б}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```